# Excluding testing subdomain from being crawled by search engines (w/ SVN Repository)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web-crawler, robots.txt, google-search-console

I have:

- domain.com
- testing.domain.com

I want domain.com to be crawled and indexed by search engines, but not testing.domain.com

The testing domain and main domain share the same SVN repository, so I'm not sure if separate robots.txt files would work...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) Create separate robots.txt file (name it **robots_testing.txt**, for example).

2) Add this rule into your .htaccess in website root folder:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =testing.example.com
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ /robots_testing.txt [L]
```

It will rewrite (internal redirect) any request for `robots.txt` to `robots_testing.txt` IF domain name = `testing.example.com`.

Alternatively, do opposite -- rewrite all requests for `robots.txt` to `robots_disabled.txt` for all domains except `example.com`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=example.com
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ /robots_disabled.txt [L]
```

Comment: what about the www version of testing.example.com - do i need a separate rule for that?

Answer (score 2):

testing.domain.com should have it own robots.txt file as follows

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

User-agent: Googlebot
Noindex: /
```

located at http://testing.domain.com/robots.txt
This will disallow all bot user-agents and as google looks at the Noindex as well we'll just though it in for good measure.

You could also add your sub domain to webmaster tools - block by robots.txt and submit a site removal (though this will be for google only). For some more info have a look at
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/url-removal-explained-part-i-urls.html

Comment: The files for both the testing and main domain are stored in the same SVN repository, and having separate robots.txt files would be pretty inconvenient...Any workaround to this?

Comment: Environment variables